# How to esitimate the multi-index sum below

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, partial-differential-equations

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be multi index in $\mathbb{N}^d$. $m$ is some positive integer.

Define $\alpha\le \beta$ when each component $\alpha_i\le \beta_i$  and $|\alpha| = \sum_i\alpha_i$

Given $c_\beta \ge 0$ .How can we esitmate the following sum has same order?

$$\sum_{|\alpha|\le m} \sum_{\beta\le \alpha}c_\beta \le C\sum_{|\beta|\le m}c_\beta$$

I don't know how to compute it,since so may terms in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{|\alpha|\leqslant m}\sum_{\beta\leqslant\alpha}c_\beta=\sum_{|\beta|\leqslant m}n_\beta c_\beta$ where $n_\beta=\#\{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^d : |\alpha|\leqslant m,\,\alpha\geqslant\beta\}$.

The greatest $n_\beta$ is at $\beta=0$ (assuming $0\in\mathbb{N}$), so you're fine with $C=n_0=\binom{m+d-1}{m}$.

Comment: thanks I have worked it out,since all the things are finite,the order must be the same